# Get list of files changed on p4

Tags: perforce, p4v

I want to get the list of files that has been changed on server since last sync down on a particular branch.
I want only the files that has been changed/added on the server. I am not at all concerned with the locally changed files.

Answer (score 2):

`p4 sync -n` shows you the files that will be synced.

`p4 sync -N` gives you a summary.

Comment: yeah this does it. But when I try to capture the logs in a file ```p4 sync -n >>> out.txt```, I get the action name too along with the filename
```//depot/config/MysettingsLoc.inf#6 - updating E:/P4_workspaces\MysettingsLoc.inf```

Comment: any way to remove the extra info and get just the filenames

Comment: Some sort of `sed` command, or whatever you use for text processing on Windows.